# Let $G$ be a non-abelian group. Prove that $Z(G) \subsetneq C(g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a non-abelian group. Prove that $Z(G)$ is a proper subset of $C(g)$.

Here $Z(G)$ means the center of $G$ and $C(g)$ means the centralizer of the element $g \in G$.

This seems really intuitive but I am having trouble formalizing this.  Any help?
My problem is proving that an element in $C(g)$ is not in $Z(G)$.  It is readily apparent that $h \in Z(G) \implies h \in C(g)$

Answer (score 6):

If $g$ is in the center of $G$, then $C(g)=G\neq Z(G)$. If $g$ is not in the center of $G$, then $g$ is in $C(g)$ but not in $Z(G)$.